Can't tzaddikim get Hashem to resolve certain issues based on their merits?
I know the question is a little pedantic because one could take it all the way and ask tzaddikim to get us full geula, fix everyone's health and money issues among other problems but still.
For example, the situation in Israel is dire with respect to intra-Jewish relations, neighbourly relations and international relations. One could argue it's looking so desperate it is hardly in our hands to fix it. I'm not even getting into whether Israel's problems are about its own wrongdoings or unjustified ostracisation and some kind of back luck.
The point is that we believe tzaddikim to be able to "pull favours" and it is hard to understand why all these miracles generally revolve around someone conceiving a child or overcoming a health issue and not these global problems that the entire Jewish world is facing.
You could argue that Israel's problems will get resolved when everyone makes teshuva and starts observing mitzvos but then how about climate change, most of it is caused by non-Jews, probably even righteous as far as Noachide laws are concerned.
People might also argue there aren't any tzaddikim in our generation but surely there must be at least 36? What are they up to exactly and why aren't they taking care of us?
You could also say - if not for what are they getting done, things would be much worse and that they are in fact solving all kinds of problems by converting their merits to tangible favours but then they are clearly not doing a good job. If this is the best they can do are they tzaddikim or half-tzaddikim?

At least regarding climate change, it can be argued that nothing really bad will actually happen until the latest projected post-messianic era (in a few centuries), when humanity will be entirely good, and as a result Hashem will not use climate change to oppress us. Until then, the worst things will be a significant but manageable increase in storms and the diminishing of non-critical biodiversity. Thus, climate change might not be considerable as a counterexample.

why aren't they taking care of us? sorry to also be pedantic, but notwithstanding the 3 figure number of Jews who this statement definitely applies to, there are 7 figure Jews in the world right now who, as far as I can tell, are all doing pretty alright (if a little stressed and anxious for the most part, but not sure our tzaddikim's looking after of us covers that very much)


The point is that we believe tzaddikim to be able to "pull favours" and it is hard to understand why all these miracles generally revolve around someone conceiving a child or overcoming a health issue and not these global problems that the entire Jewish world is facing

The question seems to be  if Tzadikim  sometimes have the ability to change things on a micro level why can't they also do so on a macro global level as well?
If that is the question why stop by the situation in Israel why don't they just bring Moshiach? The Gemora (Bava Metzia 85b) says that Eliyohu Hanavi told Rav Yehuda Hanosi that if Rav Chiya and his sons would daven for Moshiach, he would come. Rav Yehuda Hanosi made a fast day and got them to daven but in Shomayim they found other ways to prevent them from their tefila and bringing him.  (see inside for more detail) because Hashem had not decided it was the time yet.
The Gemora says that in Shomayim they were upset at Eliyohu Hanavi for telling the above to Rav Yehuda Hanasi.
It would be similar with other g'zeiras that were made on a macro global level.
Furthermore those who currently causing the difficulties in Eretz Yisroel are human beings with bechira.  Tzadikim do not have the power to control other people's bechira.

No need to control bechira, you merely need to control the circumstances around them to soft push them to certain choices. But even regardless of any choices they make, you can definitely affect their success vs success of Klal Yisroel through all kinds of fortunes and misfortunes (weather, things getting lost or found etc etc examples are endless).

Controlling the circumstances people operate in is just another way of taking away their bechira. If such a thing were humanly possible on such a large global level then no one would have the bechira to become a major Rasha. Tzadkim would just change the circumstances the guy is in and push him into a different direction.  Moreover if tzadkim are always capable of getting Hashem to change things like  the weather, what is the whole meshcta Taanis about? Just have some tzadkim daven and rain will come etc,

Plenty of ways to be a major rasha le-makom and to other reshoim, why do beynoynim need to get mixed up in all this. Besides, Moishe Rabbeinu did for klal Yisroel time after time, we obviously live in different circumstances but it doesn’t seem so inconceivable. And in any case what would be the red / out of bounds line for tzaddikim and their miracles?
